# Kereberos Authentication

Tags: kerberos, spnego

I have a REST client. Using this I want to access a  server which has kerberos authentication enabled.
I have very new to this. From what I understand, we need username and password and then krb5.conf and login.conf file.

I want to implement this using JAVA. Currently we were using sourceforge.spnego library. Is there any other library which we can use?

Comment: Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].